# PHP and Python displaying different times

Tags: php, python

I have a Python application that stores the local time into a mySQL database and a PHP application that displays that date/time through a Web interface.  I'm observing a constant offset (from GMT) of the displayed date/time.

I can find nothing in the PHP / Python documentation to explain this difference.

The Python application stores the local time:

```
import time
localTime = int(time.time())
```

The PHP application then retrieves the time and displays it:

```
 date('n/j/y H:i:s', $bg['last_polled'])
```

where $bg retrieves the entry from the mySQL database.

Why don't these two agree on what localtime is (both applications are running on same server)

Comment: What value is the constant offset?

Comment: Is the difference the same as your local timezone's difference from GMT?

Comment: You should provide actual data: the datetime as stored in MySQL, as displayed by PHP and you should log the date in your Python program. That way we _could_ help you (and you might want to specify your TZ if relevant)

Comment: lots of sources of error: PHP, MySQL, Python, even the system itself. I suggest *always* use times *with timezones* as native objects or strings. `time.time()` is fast and easy but it's always vague.  Always, or when possible, store timestamps as UTC (aka GMT) - it makes things much easier.

Comment: What does `echo date ('n/j/y H:i:s');` display in PHP? The correct local time? Or the local time with the offset applied? Similarly, what does `echo date("n/j/y H:i:s", 1409076361);` display? A time roughly equivalent to when I write this comment?

Comment: Also, try adding `TO` to the end of your date format string. Is the indicated time zone accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted above, the timezone needs to be explicitly set.  Ideally in a php.ini file.  As a practical matter, I found at least two instances of php.ini and decided to take the coward's way out and add the following to startup.php:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Louisville');
```

The timezones for the US are far from intuitive (and largely depricated.  I see a lot of entries to cover Indiana when parts of the state ignored DST)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are storing the date as an integer timestamp, I think the problem is on PHP side. Have you set PHP date.timezone INI setting correctly?

Here is some more info about that setting: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone

Comment: We have a winner !!    I feel foolish I didn't look in the PHP.ini file before.

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing a timestamp `2014-08-25 12:11:00` or a Unix Epoch `2147483647`?  Check to see what data type PHP is reading and how it is displayed.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear.  Time is stored as Unix Epoch from Python (time.time()) and truncated to an integer.   Python documentation says time.time() is local time

Comment: @user3073001, where in the Python doc does it say that `time.time()` is local time?